# how pass aplication_id parameter to paypal sdk in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, paypal

i´m reading the documentation of paypal https://developer.paypal.com/limited-release/paypal-mobile-checkout/android/ ,in the example show
[image]

but i have the next error, the parameters doesn´t match. Only works when i remove this parameter
BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "://paypalpay", how i can pass the parameter even later?
[image]

Comment: you have to register application with PayPal SDK to obtain application id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   config= PayPalConfiguration().environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX).clientId(client_id)
        .environment(CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT)
        .merchantName("Example Merchant")
        .merchantPrivacyPolicyUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/privacy"))
        .merchantUserAgreementUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/legal"))
    var i= Intent(this, PayPalService::class.java)
    i.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,config)
    startService(i)
```